# Reference ASP.NET TextBox Control in AngularJS by ID instead of Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, webforms

I have a legacy application that I'm trying to add some Angular form validation features for the client side to be a little nicer. It's a WebForms application and it's using Master Pages.

The issue I'm running into is when I try to validate the form I need to reference the control by it's name attribute which ASP.NET auto generates (even when ClientIDMode = Static). I can't change the control to not be server side.

Is there a way I can reference the control by it's ID instead of name in AngularJS?

My TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" data-ng-model="formObj.textValue" ID="txtTextBox" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static" MaxLength="100" required />
```

The Angular code:

```
$scope.validateForm = function (myForm) {
    if (myForm.txtTextBox.$invalid) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};
```

It comes back as an error because .NET generates the name as

```
<input name="ctl00$Content$txtTextBox" maxlength="100" id="txtTextBox" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-binding ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength" data-ng-model="formObj.textValue" required="">
```

I don't want to hard code the ctl00$Content$txtTextBox into the name because this could easily change if someone ever moved the control or changed the structure. Is there some way I can reference the control by it's ID value which is always the same? Or is there some other .NET / Angular magic I can use to get around this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `ClientIDMode="Static"` should in ASP.NET 4.0 or above. What version of ASP.NET are you running?

Comment: @Win It's 4.0. Static Client ID is set but it only affects the ID attribute. The name attribute is still auto generated when it's rendered out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is to get the element name by id and then use the name with [ ] notation for validation.

try something like below.

```
myForm[document.getElementById("txtTextBox").getAttribute("name")].$invalid
```

Here is the Plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/WMQ4Fb579PUW9C5t3124

Comment: Ah, of course. I knew there was something simple I just wasn't thinking of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have used angular on web forms and I think its best to not mix asp.net controls with angular. Is there a reason why you can just use input field?

But if you do have to use it, to fix your particular problem you can use [ClientIDMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)